# iOSアプリ譲渡後のプッシュ通知

Tags: ios, push-notification

Appストアに公開されているiOSアプリ（プッシュ通知を実装）を、現在のアカウント（アカウントA）から新しいアカウント（アカウントB）にiTunes connect経由で譲渡しようと考えております。

譲渡後のプッシュ通知について下記２点教えて頂けますでしょうか？

①譲渡前のユーザー（アカウントAの時のユーザー）には、譲渡前と同様に譲渡後もプッシュ通知を送信する事は可能でしょうか？

②譲渡後のユーザー（アカウントBの時のユーザー）には、アプリに何ら変更を加える事なしに、プッシュ通知を送る事は可能でしょうか？

①、②について不可能な場合、プッシュ通知を送れるようになるプロセスについて教えて頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

直接的な回答というよりは代替案なのですが、
以前プッシュ通知に悩んだ者として知見を共有させて頂ければと思います。

まず、iTunes connect経由でアプリの所属アカウントを変更した場合に、
デバイストークンIDがどうなるかという質問ですが、
実際に経験したことがないため、お答えできません...。

ただ、デバイストークンIDは変更が生じる前提で実装されることをオススメ致します。
理由としては、

- iOS6→iOS7のアップデートタイミングでデバイストークンIDの仕様が変更されました
  iOS6までは **デバイスごとの割当** でしたが、iOS7からは **デバイス＆アプリごとに割当** に変更されました。
- iOS9から **アプリをインストール度にデバイストークンIDが変更** されるようになりました。
  つまり、一度アンインストールして、インストールし直すとデバイストークンIDが変更されるということです。
- 今年中に２点の仕様変更が予定されています。
  1: デバイストークンIDの **サイズが大きくなる** (32bytes→100bytesに変更)
  2: development, productionの **証明書が1つになる** (以前は、証明書ごとに別IDでした)

といった過去の背景と今後の予定があるためです。

よって、

- 発行されたデバイストークンIDを端末内部に保持
- アプリ起動ごとに(停止状態から起動した場合に)デバイストークンIDを確認
- 確認したデバイストークンIDが端末内部に保存したデバイストークンIDと異なる場合は値を更新(端末内部およびサーバサイドのDBも更新)

とされるのが良いと思います。

これであれば、懸念されていることにも対応可能になるかと思います。

もちろん、ユーザがアプリを起動しないと更新されませんが、
デバイストークンIDはiOS更新ごとに仕様が変わるものなので、
プッシュ通知が届くか否かはベストエフォートと考えた方が良いです。

少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

これはあくまで予測なので保証し兼ねますが、答えようと思います。

この質問は、「各ユーザーはなんらかのサーバーに送っているPush通知のID」の扱いがアカウント移譲後にどのようになるかというものだと解釈しました。
予想としては二通りあります。
・今まで使っていたIDが無効になる
・IDは無効にならない。
・証明書等が無効になり一切送れなくなる。

1番目の場合、既存ユーザーでアクティブユーザーでない場合、2度と送られなくなります。新規ユーザーには影響ありません。
2番目の場合、既存ユーザーにも新規ユーザーにも送る事ができます。一番望ましいパターンです。
3番目の場合、送る事は出来ません。諦めて再実装するしかありません。

アカウントの移譲の挙動はほとんどの人は経験がない事です。実際にどのようになるか不明です。リスクを覚悟した上で、素早く対応できる体制をとる事が、よりよい対策だと思います。